# Compare two fields within different table using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have two tables employees and customers , i've gave the schema below.

```
Customers('id' , 'username', 'location');

Employees('id' , 'EmployeeID' , 'CustomerID', 'location');
```

Currently I can use a query to retrieve customers details like the below query , note this is when the user is logged into the system hence the Auth::

```
$customerQuery1 = DB::table('customer')
            ->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())  
            ->where('item', '=' , Auth::customer()->recommendation)  
            ->get();
```

Each Employee has many customers ,I want other customers to see other customer items so i have attach the `CustomerID` field which is a foreign key and relates to the `id` field within the Customer table.

I've tried something like the below however I think I may need a join query but i'm unsure.

```
$query2 =  DB::table('Customer','Employee')
        ->select('username')
        ->where(['EmployeeID' => Auth::id(), 'CustomerID' => 'id']) 
        ->get(); 

$query2 =  DB::table('Customer')
        ->select('username')
        ->join('Employee', 'Customer.id', '=', 'Employee.CustomerID')             
        ->where(['EmployeeID' => Auth::id(), 'CustomerID' => 'id']) 
        ->get();
```

I am then returning the values to my blade file like the below

```
 return view ('pages.dashboard')
 ->with('query1',$query1)
```

and then Im using php indentation within my blade file to return the users data

```
 @foreach ($query1 as $Userfound)
 {{ $Userfound->username}}</p> 

@endforeach
```

Actual Query needed in plain english

so I need to select a customer  , where CustomerID == id

NOTE: id is from the customers table, CustomerID stored in the Employees table.

Comment: So what is it you want to accomplish exactly with the query? What should be the expected result?

Comment: you can try laravel relationship but for that you need to create Model file for your table.

for more reference you can check below link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I can test the results my self  , i'm returning $query or the variable to my blade file. @DeesOomens . I'll update my post to show you

Comment: What do you mean by "I want other customers to see other customer items"?

Comment: I kind like have a following system , I want other customer to see other customers details.

Comment: @NirajSavaliya ops , forgot my model files , I'll update my post now

Answer (score 1):

You can create Models using Laravel, for example:

Employee.php

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Customer');
}
```

Customer.php

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```

Which you can access like so:

```
$customer = Customer::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail();
```

or

```
$employee = Employee::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->firstOrFail();
```

And to see an employee's customers:

```
$employee->customers()->get();
```

Or to see the other customers of `$customer`'s employer:

```
$customer->employee()->customers()->get();
```

Comment: @party-ring When using relations, you need to either use `->get()` to finish the eloquent builder, or use `->customer` (without `()`) which will return all as expected.

Comment: @party-ring this is the error message i receive SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'musicdatabase.follower_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `follower`.*, `follower_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `follower_user`.`follower_id` as `pivot_follower_id` from `follower` inner join `follower_user` on `follower`.`id` = `follower_user`.`follower_id` where `follower_user`.`user_id` = 1)

Comment: i'll give an example of what I want the actual output to be in my post